# Is an error in a Rent Increase Notice binding?

Tags: contract-law, residential-lease, australia

I have just received a letter and email from my landlord stating that the rent will be increased in accordance with Residential Tenancies Act 1997.

Increased rent will be $600.00 per month, an increase of $20 per week.

Current rent is $280 a week. Therefore I suspect it was meant to state $600.00 per fortnight.

Is this letter legally binding?  Can I get half price rent from this error?

Current lease ends in Jan. The agent has said the owner would like to offer me a new lease on the above terms.

Comment: Considering that the two sentences contradict each other (an increase of $20 per week would not result in a price of $600 per month), the contract [might be considered invalid in court](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2263) if you tried to push that. It's probably not a good idea to hope they'll just accept that situation, especially since the real estate agent seems to be acting on behalf of the actual owner. The owner may not have even seen this yet and needs to grant final approval (via signature), so he might decline when he sees it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see where you are coming from and I don't really plan on chasing this. More or less want to know how badly the realestate has stuffed up. This is not the first issue I have had with them. 

I think I will just wait until they realise the error and then they will need to send a new letter with another 60days notice period.